# Full crawl is not working getting content access account password error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, access, content, crawl

I am using SharePoint enterprise 2013, My search service is stopped and i am unable to do crawl. if i start full crawl its stopping immediately with an error in the crawl log

> "The password for the content access account cannot be decrypted
>   because it was stored with different credentials. Re-type the password
>   for the account used to crawl this content"

even I tried to retype the password of default content access account, still same error.
and search application topology not showing the status of crawl and other details for one particular server.
[image: topology looks like this]

Answer (score 0):

Use user@domain.local instead of domain\user when specify the Default Content Access Account.

If the issue exists, go to the relevant server->Start->Run->services.msc->check if the “SharePoint Server Search 15” and “SharePoint Search Host Controller” features are running.

Comment: if i change to content access account to another service account crawl is working. But i cannot use that service account, since it has the highest privilege and it is farm account .and all the services are running properly .

Comment: Does your crawl account have read access to the content?